# Collapsed Navbar not working react and bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

For some reason the collapsed navbar icon does not expand when clicked on on smaller screens. I copied the example from bootstrap 5 and made sure to include bootstrap css/js and jquery.

```
class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="NavBar">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                      <div className="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                        <HashLink className="navbar-brand" to="/#app">
                            Site
                        </HashLink>
                        <HashLink className="nav-link" to="/#about">
                            About
                        </HashLink>
                        <HashLink className="nav-link" to="/#skills">
                            Skills
                        </HashLink>
                        <HashLink className="nav-link" to="/#experience">
                            Experience
                        </HashLink>
                        <Link className="nav-link" to="/calculator">
                            Calculator
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: From your description and the code you give above, it should work. Check out the output code to find out the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer here that works via react hooks: https://dev.to/johnotu/how-to-toggle-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-button-in-react-without-jquery-joo

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Logo from '../images/logo_512x512.png';

const TopNav = props => {
  const [isNavCollapsed, setIsNavCollapsed] = useState(true);

  const handleNavCollapse = () => setIsNavCollapsed(!isNavCollapsed);

  return (
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-info font-weight-bolder" href="/">
        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" width="36" height="36" className="vertical-align-middle" />
        <span className="">Discounter</span>
      </a>
      <button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="navbarsExample09" aria-expanded={!isNavCollapsed ? true : false} aria-label="Toggle navigation" onClick={handleNavCollapse}>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class={`${isNavCollapsed ? 'collapse' : ''} navbar-collapse`} id="navbarsExample09">
        <a className="nav-link text-info" href="/contact">Support</a>
        <a className="nav-link text-info" href="/login">Login</a>
        <a href="/request-demo" className="btn btn-sm btn-info nav-link text-white" >Request demo</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default TopNav;
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is we didn't add the bootstrap js file
so, add this in App.js file

```
  import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```

Comment: I added but still not working..

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issues, i fixed them by adding **-bs** to data-toggle & data-target. thus turning them to data-bs-toggle & data-bs-target respectively.

Here are my package.json dependencies:

- "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
- "jquery": "^3.6.0",
- "popper.js":
  "^1.16.1",
- "react": "^18.2.0",
- "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

Example code:

> *Changed from*

```
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

> Changed to:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

Comment: The project I'm working on was previously using Bootstrap 4, now 5, all that was missing was the "-bs" for the collapse to work. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to import this.
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

Navbar
    
      
    
    
      
        
          Home
        
        
          Link
        
        
          
            Dropdown

Action

Another action

Something else here

Disabled
        
      
      
        
        Search

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).